# select rowid of certain row when using group by in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, group-by

I have a query in SQLite where I group by a certain column and use an aggregate function MAX on another column in the select statement. Now I also want the rowid of the row which holds the value that is displayed by the MAX aggregate. I know that this must be a unique row because of the primary key constraint. I can't figure out how to write the query. See the following example:

```
create table t1 (c1, c2, constraint t1_pk primary key (c1, c2));

insert into t1 values ('boys', 1);
insert into t1 values ('boys', 2);
insert into t1 values ('girls', 1);
insert into t1 values ('girls', 2);
```

Now I have the table with the primary constraint over both columns. A SELECT query for the table gives the following output:

```
sqlite> select rowid, * from t1;

rowid|c1|c2
1|boys|1
2|boys|2
3|girls|1
4|girls|2
```

Now I want to group by c1 and select the MAX of c2. Then I want the rowid of the row which holds the values displayed now. See the following queries:

```
sqlite> select rowid, c1, max(c2) from t1 group by c1;

rowid|c1|max(c2)
2|boys|2
4|girls|2

sqlite> select rowid, c1, min(c2) from t1 group by c1;

rowid|c1|min(c2)
2|boys|1
4|girls|1
```

The second query with the MIN aggregate should return the rowids of the rows holding the MIN values, this is what I want to achieve:

```
rowid|c1|min(c2)
1|boys|1
3|girls|1
```

Now I've tried the following subselect, which doesn't work either because it gives an error:

```
sqlite> select (select rowid from t1 b where b.c1 = a.c1 and b.c2 = max(a.c2)), a.c1, max(a.c2) from t1 a group by a.c1;

Error: misuse of aggregate function max()

sqlite> select (select rowid from t1 b where b.c1 = a.c1 and b.c2 = min(a.c2)), a.c1, min(a.c2) from t1 a group by a.c1;

Error: misuse of aggregate function min()
```

The last thing I've tried is a subquery in the FROM clause, which also doesn't work:

```
sqlite> select
   ...>         (select rowid from t1 b where b.c1 = c.c1 and b.c2 = c.c2),
   ...>         c1,
   ...>         c2
   ...> from
   ...>         (select a.c1, max(a.c2) as c2 from t1 a group by a.c1) c;

Error: misuse of aggregate: max()

sqlite> select
   ...>         (select rowid from t1 b where b.c1 = c.c1 and b.c2 = max(c.c2)),
   ...>         c.c1,
   ...>         max(c.c2)
   ...> from
   ...>         (select a.c1, a.c2 from t1 a group by a.c1) c;

Error: misuse of aggregate function max()
```

Is there any solution for my problem? I really don't know what else I could try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, try like this:

```
select rowid, c1, min(c2) from t1 a
where c2=(select min(c2) from t1 b where b.c1=a.c1) 
group by rowid,c1;
```

check the [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/77b75/5)

Comment: By the way, I didn't know about FIDDLE but it looks really interesting, thank you for this tipp too.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, following the answer by @Pradeeshnarayan, I have been obliged to improve it to make it work in Oracle.
"Group by" clause is useless

```
select rowid, c1, c2 from t1 a
where c2=(select min(c2) from t1 b where b.c1=a.c1);
```